# What is a Sandbox

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, sandbox

When anti-viruses run some application in a virtual environment called a "sandbox", how does this sandbox precisely work from the Windows kernel point of view?

Is it hard to write such a sandbox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At a high level such sandboxes are kernel drivers which intercept calls to APIs, and modify the results those APIs return using hooking. How an entire sandboxing solution works under the hood though, could easily fill several books.

As for difficulty, it's probably one of the harder things you could ever possibly write. Not only do you have to provide hooks for most everything the operating system kernel provides, but you have to prevent the application from accessing the memory space of other processes, you have to have a way to save the state of the changes a program makes so that the program does not realize it's running under a sandbox. You have to do all of this in Kernel mode, which effectively limits you to using C, and forces you to deal with different kinds of memory, e.g. paged pool and nonpaged pool. Oh, and you have to do all of this **very** fast, so that the user feels it's worthwhile to run applications inside your sandbox. 50+% performance hits won't be tolerated by most users.

Comment: On the performance point - it's not just user apps, one strategy used by some AV programs is to execute the code being examined on a virtual copy of the environment, and look for suspect activity. That too has performance requirements, of course, especially when scanning a lot of files at once, but UI responsiveness of the code under test isn't relevant.

Comment: @Steve: That's one way of implementing A/V tools, but that is not a sandbox. That's a Host-based Intrusion Prevention System (HIPS). Those are substantially less difficult than true sandboxes.

Comment: Guys, are there any books about topics like these?

Comment: @James: Unlikely. The only group that I know of that has even attempted something like this is the Sandboxie people -- and nowadays modern hypervisors have pretty much eliminated most of the demand for sandboxes. (After all, code might be able to break out of a sandbox because it owns the CPU while it's running; but it can't break out of a hypervisor because the hypervisor owns the CPU the whole time)